# Formatting of plugin.xml file in Eclipse isn't working

Tags: xml, eclipse, tabs, spaces

**CentOS Linux 7 (Core)**

**Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers
Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Build id: 20190614-1200**

I have XML files someone else wrote.  Those files are indented with tabs.  I can't get Eclipse to covert those tables to spaces.

I've set Windows > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor  to "Indent Using Spaces"

I've opened the file in the XML editor, selected all of the code, and  pressed Ctrl Shift F

No results.

---

**Update:**

---

This is the content of workspace/.metadata/.log when opening "plugin.xml" in the XML editor, selecting all of the code, and excecuting Ctrl Shift F

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2020-02-06 10:25:26.212 !MESSAGE
>   StructuredTextEditor being used without StructuredDocument
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2020-02-06 10:25:26.213 !MESSAGE
>   Input Name: plugin.xml
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2020-02-06 10:25:26.213 !MESSAGE
>   Unexpected IDocumentProvider implementation:
>   org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2020-02-06 10:25:26.213 !MESSAGE
>   Unexpected IDocument implementation:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-02-06 10:25:40.123
>   !MESSAGE Execution exception for:
>   ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.format.document,Format,
>         Format selection,
>         Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
>         org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@2ceb0ef3,
>         ,,true),null) in    context chain: WorkbenchContext ->
>   TrimmedWindowImpl (IDEWindow) Context -> PerspectiveImpl
>   (org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective) Context -> PartImpl
>   (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor) 
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPartContext
>   -> MultiPageEditorSite (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor) !STACK 0 org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: While executing
>   the action, an exception occurred     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:95)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:320)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:653)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:443)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$2(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1796)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1399)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1426)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1409)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1450)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.gtk_key_press_event(Widget.java:819)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_key_press_event(Control.java:3978)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_key_press_event(Composite.java:857)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2238)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6814)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6132)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_main_do_event(GTK.java:4166)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1429)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1585)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4661)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.doOperation(StructuredTextViewer.java:567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction.lambda$0(TextOperationAction.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction.run(TextOperationAction.java:130)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:121)
>     ... 59 more

Comment: Is the file read-only? Are these plug-in/feature/Eclipse-related XML files? Are there any messages in the Error Log?

Comment: The files were not read only.  I was able to manually to remove some tab marks.  Where would I find the Error Log?

Comment: Check for it in the list of Views (Window->Show View, possibly under Other...) or in the workspace directory as a hidden file in a hidden directory, `.metadata/.log`.

Comment: I added the contents of my .metadata/.log to my post.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You have to edit `plugin.xml` files in the Plug-in Manifest Editor. The underlying text document implementation is different due to imperfect API implementations in the "normal" XML Editor.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried Ctrl Shift F in the Manifest Editor.  I pushed some tags out of line and no beautification took place.

Comment: That's surprising. I don't see a Format command on its Edit or Source menus. I guess it...can't? You might have to copy the contents to a differently named file and format them there.